# Find ideal width and height of n same rectangles inside a rectangle

Tags: geometry, area, surfaces, ratio

I have a rectangle, its width is **a** and its height is **b**

I want to cover a maximum of surface from that rectangle with **n** rectangles, those rectangles must have the same dimensions and respect a ratio of **w** on **h**

how can I compute the dimensions of the **n** rectangles ?

I tried the following

$$c = \sqrt{a*b* w/h \over n}$$

$$width = c * w$$
$$height = c * h$$

But it's not perfectly working because this is looking for covering the entire rectangle (so in some cases the result dimensions make a bigger rectangle then the rectangle ab

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rectangle]

Unless Fig. 1 depicts an example of what you are expecting, don't read any further, because the description given below is based on it.

It is assumed that $a$, $b$, $h$, $w$, and $n$ are given. Let the height of the small rectangles be $k$. Then, the width of the small rectangles is equal to $k\frac{w}{h}$. Now, we can find out how many small rectangles we need to cover the large rectangle as shown below

$$\mathrm{Nr.\space of\space small\space rectangles\space on\space a\space column} =n_c= \Big\lfloor \frac{b}{k}\Big\rfloor \le \frac{b}{k}\qquad\quad\space$$

$$\mathrm{Nr.\space of\space small\space rectangles\space on\space a\space row} = n_r=\Big\lfloor \frac{a}{k} \times \frac{h}{w}\Big\rfloor \le \frac{a}{k} \times \frac{h}{w}$$

$$\therefore\quad n = n_c\times n_r = \Big\lfloor \frac{b}{k}\Big\rfloor \times \Big\lfloor \frac{a}{k} \times \frac{h}{w}\Big\rfloor \le \frac{a}{k}\times \frac{b}{k}\times \frac{h}{w}.$$

As you see, the relationship between $n$ and the unknown $k$ has been obtained using floor functions. These functions prevent us from making $k$ the subject of an equation, which we need to determine both the height and the width of the small rectangles. Therefore, I think that your question cannot be resolved mathematically. However, one may find a solution experimentally.

Comment: I I have to test your solution experimentaly to be sure, tell me if I'm wrong but as I understood, you are sharing the area of the big rectangle in n parts, giving you the area of a small rectangle then apply the ratio to it to get its width and height of the small. Meaning that you are seeking for an equality between big rectangle area and the sum of the small rectangles areas. But in my problem there is one more constraint: the small rectangles can't be cut or rotate to fit the whole big rectangle, sometimes the sum of small rectangles areas could be less than the big rectangle area

Comment: So area of a small rectangle could be inferior to a * b / n

Comment: @Xeno I read your comments. I think I now know what you want. It is definitely not what I have given in my answer of yesterday. I hope to revise my answer in a few hours. So, please have patient.

Comment: @Xeno I have just posted a revised answer to your question. Please read it and let me know whether you agree with me or not.

Comment: Fig. 1 is exactly what I'm looking for, you answer seems really promising, I will take a closer look on it tomorrow !

Comment: thank you for the solution, I think I could implement something based on that, however do you think is there any mathematical way to know the width and height of a rectangle if n = 1 ?